# How to use sum if to add values if the weekdays in a range match a particular cell

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs, excel-2016

I have an excel document that has 101 worksheets. 100 of the worksheets contain data for a particular month i.e. one of the worksheets is called 'May 2010', followed by a worksheet called 'June 2010'. On each of these sheets there is a list of dates in column A, and a list of revenue $s in column B.

I'm creating a summary sheet that is going to use the indirect function to look at all the different sheets and basically sum all of the revenue made on each day of the week in each month. For example I want to sum all the revenue made on Tuesdays in October of 2014.

I was trying to use an array function like so:

```
=SUM((--WEEKDAY(('May 2010'!A2:A22)=2)*(('May 2010'!B2:B22))))
```

I found this online. I am trying to see if i can sum all of the revenue values in column B on the sheet entitled 'May 2010' if the corresponding value in column A is a Monday. The values in column A are of the form '11-May'

I think my problem is that i'm trying to check the weekday of a range of values but I'm not really sure. I don't fully understand how array functions work or even if i'm supposed to be using them. I open to any suggestions as long as it doesn't require me to go through each of my 100 sheets manually and create a column that contains the weekdays of the corresponding dates. Any thoughts?

Comment: So does the formula you give work as expected? And you simply want it extending to work over multiple worksheets, not just one?

Comment: If you click on one of the dates in your May 2010 sheet, does it display the correct year ie 11-May shows (in US format) 5/11/2010?

Comment: @XORLX i actually have the part to make it work over multiple sheets already done. I was just looking for the answer on how to make it work on one  sheet. The multiple sheets thing i can do with indirect

Comment: @TomSharpe yes it does display the correct year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the brackets aren't quite right.

```
=SUM(((WEEKDAY('May 2010'!A2:A22)=2)*('May 2010'!B2:B22)))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((WEEKDAY('May 2010'!A2:A22)=2)*('May 2010'!B2:B22)))
```

if you prefer not to have to enter it as an array formula.

If as @XOR LX suggests you actually want to repeat this over all of your sheets, it is a bit more tricky.

Comment: I used the sum product and it worked flawlessly. Can you explain what this function is doing?/why it works? I don't really understand why the multiplication is used and what the weekday function is doing. Is it checking if the weekday of each value matches 2 (monday) and then if it does it give a 1 for true or a 0 for false? and then multiplies that by the value in the corresponding cell in column b?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right about 1's and 0's, using weekday, and the multiplication. The reason multiplication is used in an array formula rather than the more obvious AND is that AND looks at all the values you give it and combines them, but it only delivers a single result which is not what you want. Multiplication here multiplies and delivers an array with one result for each pair of values fed to it and also coerces TRUE/FALSE values to 1's and 0's so you don't need to put --. SUMPRODUCT then adds the array elements. See https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

Comment: Okay awesome, everything is working as planned now. Thanks for all the help!